# Invalid Password Reset Token

Tags: passwords, token, reset

I have an app hosted in Heroku. It is a video streaming app built in Ruby. I'm the owner, but not the developer, who is no longer available. Recently the reset password process has stopped working. The process works up until the point a user enters a new password, then we get an error indicating the "Reset password token is invalid". What kinds of things can cause this? Any advice on where to start looking. Again, I'm not a developer, but I'd like to exhaust the obvious stuff before I try t find someone to take this on.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jywVn.png)

Comment: Unless you share the codes related to that, it is not possible to tell. Each developer has his own way of doing things.

Comment: It best advice to accompany your question with the code full code base where you have the problem or the code snipet you think the problem is coming from. If you post a question with out a code that question happens to have high percentage of getting down votes and not getting answered. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) prior to asking a question and try to follow the structure suggested by the help documentation.